# Including Local Jars In Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I'm attempting to use "HTTPBuilder" within my simple Groovy script. When I use '@Grab' to import the dependency, everything works fine. Though, I'd like to keep the jar within a different directory and import it using the classLoader function. I've copied the 'http-builder-0.7.jar' that '@Grab' placed into my grapes directory and pasted it into the same directory my Groovy script is running (on Windows). I then comment out the '@Grab' statement and include the classLoader, but get this error:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: C:\Groovy Scripts\test.groovy: 9: unable to resolve
>   class HTTPBuilder

Any ideas why the classLoader wouldn't be working in the script? I printed out the path of the jar when importing with '@Grab' and it's definitely using the one within the grape directory. If I uncomment the '@Grab' statement, it works again. Here's the small script...

```
//@Grab('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7')

this.getClass().classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new File("http-builder-0.7.jar").toURL())

//return new File(groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());

def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://httpbin.org/get')
```

Comment: HttpBuilder probably relies on other dependencies...  This is a slippery slope to go down

Comment: Is there a way to see what dependencies it relies on? Would this be as simple as downloading those jars and placing them within the same directory?

Comment: [You can see them in the POM here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder%7Chttp-builder%7C0.7.1%7Cjar) the problem is, it's a tree of dependencies, so the things this depends on will in turn have dependencies... Hence slippery slope. You're best using Grab, or building your script into a fat jar using something like gradle

Comment: Have you tried to put this jar on groovy-root-folder/lib?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you would be wise to use another method, such as Gradle's [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

However, this is one way to do what you're asking.

First, to get the jar and all dependencies, consider the following Gradle `build.gradle` script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7'
}

repositories { 
   jcenter()
}

clean {
    doLast {
        ant.delete(dir: 'runtime')
    }
}

task getDeps(type: Copy) {
    from sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    into 'runtime/'

    doFirst {
        ant.delete(dir: 'runtime')
        ant.mkdir(dir: 'runtime')
    }
}
```

If you run `gradle getDeps`, it will write all of the jars into `runtime`.

Then, in a Unix terminal (for example), you could set the classpath with this (using wildcard syntax from Java 6+, and assuming the path is the same `runtime` as above):

```
export CLASSPATH=.:"/user/foo/some/path/runtime/*"
```

In the same terminal, this will work:

```
import groovyx.net.http.*

def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://httpbin.org/get')

println "Ready."
```